# oracle : - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure selectCustomerData(customerId customer.customer_number%type)
AS
is 
begin
DECLARE
cusName customer.name%type;
cusAddress customer.adddress%type;

EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('No such customer found');
WHEN others THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error!!');
end;
```

Comment: `AS IS` --> `IS`

Comment: code is--->create or replace procedure selectCustomerData(customerId customer.customer_number%type)
AS
is 
begin
DECLARE
cusName customer.name%type;
cusAddress customer.adddress%type;

select name,adddress into cusName,cusAddress
from customer
where customer_number = customerId;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Name - '||cusName);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Address - '||cusAddress);
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('No such customer found');
WHEN others THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error!!');
end;

Comment: You need `AS` *or* `IS` - not both. See [the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54). Which you use is largely a matter of taste or coding style guidelines; I tend to use `AS` for standalone functions/procedures, and `IS` within packages, just because they scan better to me.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54) requires `AS` or `IS` but not both:

> [image]

---

Also, it is bad practice to catch the `OTHERS` exception as it will mask the errors and make it difficult to debug. If you know specific exceptions are going to be raised that you want to handle then catch those (like you do with `NO_DATA_FOUND`) and let the procedure fail for the other exceptions so that you (and other users) know it has failed and can debug it.

Comment: ... and even for exceptions you do really need to catch, handling should do more than display a message, as you don't know that someone calling this will ever see that. [Aimed at the OP, not MTO, clearly...]